# Css3 div gradient background animation based upon a counter value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My requirement is to change the div gradient background with an animation according to a increasing counter value.

For instance, suppose if a div background gradient is blue-white at counter=== 0.
When counter value is in range of [80, 100], then the div goes to danger range hence the background gradient is suppose to turn in red-white with animation.

I tried doing several tries, however cant do it gracefully.

Can some one tell me how can i acheive it?

Comment: Do you mandatorily need a counter or just for it to keep transitioning/changing?

Comment: Sounds like a progress bar to me...google is your friend here. [**HTML5 Doctor - Progress**](http://html5doctor.com/the-progress-element/)

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried in the question itself and explain what is going wrong

Comment: if(counter > 80 ){  change css bg [rgb values by +1 to get red ] ) , ithink rgb(220 + 1 , 0, 0)else do the opposite;

Comment: I was going to add jsfiddle today but Salathiel Genèse answer is what i was trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could made an adaptative solution. In this example, we are moving :

FROM : background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(220, 20, 20, 1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  TO : background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(20, 120, 220, 1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));

Here is the code:

1. Stylesheet

   ```
       *{
           padding: 0;
           margin: 0;
           background-color: transparent;
           background-image: none;
       }
       div{
           display: block;
           margin: 5px;
           width: 500px;
           height: 300px;
           border-radius: 5px;
           border: 1px rgba(220, 220, 220, 1) solid;
           box-shadow: 1px 3px 9px rgba(220, 220, 220, 1);
           background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(20, 120, 220, 1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
           transition-duration: .7s;
           -o-transition-duration: .7s;
           -moz-transition-duration: .7s;
           -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
       }
   ```
2. HTML BODY CONTENT

   ```
   <div data-index="0"></div>
   <b>Counter : </b><output></output>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/JQuery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
   ```
3. Javascript content

   ```
       $(function() {
           var linearDefinition = 'linear-gradient(rgba(RED, BLUE, GREEN, 1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1))';
           setInterval(function() {
               var count = parseInt($('div').data('index'));
               count = (count === 100) ? 0 : count;
               var red = 20 + ((1 + count) * 2);
               var blue = 120 - count;
               var green = 220 - (2 * (1 + count));

               // Asume this is your couter instruction
               $('div').data('index', 1 + count);
               $('output').text($('div').data(('index')));
               $('div').css('background-image', linearDefinition.replace(/RED/, red).replace(/BLUE/, blue).replace(/GREEN/, green))
           }, 50);
       });
   ```

Comment: Wow, its such a beautiful solution. Thank you for it.